# Extjs Tree how to change text color of child elements?

Tags: javascript, css, extjs

i have a tree and i want to change text color of child elements.

```
{
                text: "alegrbra",
                leaf: true,
                iconCls : 'button-with-icon icon-flag_green',
                style: {
                    'color': 'red'
                }
            }
```

i can change icon but couldnt change the color.

How can i give style that element.

Answer (score 1):

i added

> cls : 'rednode'

, and the css is

```
     .rednode{
color: red;
}
```

It fix me the problem